# Why is my code miscalculating the total force from a list of (magnitude, angle) pairs?

Tags: python, math, physics

I'm struggling to debug Python code for calculating the total force from a list of `(magnitude, angle)` pairs (with `angle` between -180 and 180).  The task requires us to:

1. For each force, break the force into its horizontal and vertical components. The horizontal component can be calculated as magnitude * cos(angle), and the vertical component can be calculated as magnitude * sin(angle).
2. Sum all the horizontal components to find the total horizontal force, and sum the vertical components to find the total vertical force.
3. Use the Pythagorean theorem to calculate the total
   magnitude: sqrt(total_horizontal ^ 2 + total_vertical ^ 2)
4. Use inverse tangent to calculate the angle:
   atan(total_vertical / total_horizontal)

Write a function called find_net_force. find_net_force should take one parameter as input: a list of 2-tuples. Each 2-tuple in the list is a (magnitude, angle) pair. angle will be in degrees between -180 and 180.

Return a 2-tuple containing the final magnitude and angle of all the forces. angle should again be in degrees. You should round both magnitude and angle to one decimal place, which you can do using round(magnitude, 1) and round(angle, 1).

At this stage, my code is:

```
from math import sin, cos, tan, asin, acos, atan2, radians, degrees, sqrt
def find_net_force(mylist):
    finalmag = 0
    horiz = 0
    vert = 0
    finalangle = 0
    for i in range(0, len(mylist)):
        horiz += (mylist[i][0] * cos(mylist[i][1]))
        vert += (mylist[i][0] * sin(mylist[i][1]))
    finalmag += sqrt((horiz ** 2) + (vert ** 2))
    finalangle = atan2(vert, horiz)
    
    return (round(finalmag, 1), round(degrees(finalangle), 1))
```

However, when if I run

```
forces = [(10, 90), (10, -90), (100, 45), (20, 180)]
print(find_net_force(forces))
```

the code returns `(76.0, 65.4)` whereas the correct answer is `(87.0, 54.4)`.  It is unclear to me why my code is miscalculating the total force.

**Question**: Why is my code miscalculating the total force from a list of (magnitude, angle) pairs?

Comment: simply use `print()` to see values in variables in different moments and compare them with your calculations on paper. It is called "print debuging". OR learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: maybe you have wrong indentation and `finalmag += sqrt(...)` should be inside `for`-loop but you have it outside `for`-loop

Comment: You forgot  to use the `radians` function.

Comment: I got the same as @Junuxx - you forgot to conver degrees to radians in `sin`, `cos`

Comment: You need to differentiate between _logical_ errors in your formulas and _coding_ errors in your code. You got the first, we care and tend to the latter.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
from math import sqrt, sin, cos, atan2, degrees, radians

def find_net_force(forces):
    h_force = sum(
            [
                force[0] * 
                cos(radians(force[1])) for force in forces
            ]
    )
    v_force = sum(
            [
                force[0] * 
                sin(radians(force[1])) for force in forces
            ]
    )
    
    r_force = round(sqrt((h_force ** 2) + (v_force ** 2)), 1)
    r_angle = round(degrees(atan2(v_force, h_force)), 1)
    
    return (r_force, r_angle)
    
forces = [(10, 90), (10, -90), (100, 45), (20, 180)]
print(find_net_force(forces))
```

Try this one. I used list comprehension.